# Getting TIFF with gdal_rasterize

Tags: qgis-3, rasterization, gdal-rasterize

How can I properly rasterize isolines with an absolute height value in QGIS 3?

When using `"gdal_rasterize"` in the source code I got tiff with `"holes"`, see image below

[image: example]